# Correct routing in angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, frontend, components

I am wondering how to properly bite the routing topic in my application.

How it's look now:
app-routing.module.ts file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/home.module#HomeModule'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/products.module#ProductsModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/404'
  }
];
```

I know its looking bad. Two same paths: ''.
But in ProductsModule my routing looks like this:

products.routing.ts file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products/:id',
    component: ProductDetailsComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':mainCategory',
    component: ProductsComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':mainCategory/:subCategory',
    component: ProductsComponent
  }
];
```

What im trying to do:

1.After go to: '/products/12331' load ProductDetailsComponent with id 12331.

Probably it's doesnt work because main module have path: ''.

Is the solution to this problem to separate the ProductDetailsComponent from the ProductsComponent?

In this way my app-routing.module.ts will looks:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/home.module#HomeModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'products',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/products.module#ProductsModule'
      },
      {
        path: ':mainCategoryId',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/products.module#CategoriesModule' (adding new module with CategoriesComponent)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/404'
  }
];
```

Second problem is that i'm loading categories from backend.
How do I solve the problem of routing to a category that does not exist?
For example i have categories:

1. Foods [Drinks,Meats, Pizza's]
2. Clothes [Shoes, Jackets, Hats]

Now if im route to:

/Foods/Drinks - should load CategoriesComponent

/Foods/Shoes - should route to /404 but how to handle it? (categories not exists)

/randomName/Drinks - should route to /404

How i can resolve it? Maybe my question's are stupid but im learning angular :)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two very different questions, which isn't ideal, but I'll try and help.

For the routing question, your 2nd routing table is better, but still isn't correct.

Using `children` for an empty path seems to defeat the purpose. You're also lazy loading HomeModule on a child route with an empty path. I'm pretty sure that doesn't work. If `home.routing.ts` actually contains child paths, just move this up to the top level as there's no need to lazy load those.

Try redoing it something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainLayoutComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'home',   // pretending this is from home.module.ts
        component: HomeComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'products',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/products.module#ProductsModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'categories',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/products.module#CategoriesModule'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/404'
    }
];
```

This is much simpler and you'll have fewer issues getting everything up and running. I'd say it's generally a bad idea `:mainCategoryId` as a top level path unless you only have one type of thing. So putting them under `categories/:mainCategory` is going to be a lot easier to understand what's going on.

Now for your second question you wanted to know how to redirect to a 404 page if given an invalid category. Because we changed the route to `categories/:mainCategory` we don't need to worry about your `/randomName/Drinks` as it'll already go to the 404. For your other examples you have a couple ways to handle it.

Probably the simplest way would be to just check the params inside your ProductsComponent.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'products-component',
    templateUrl: './products-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./products-component.component.scss'],
})
export class ProductsComponent {
    public category: string;
    public subCategory: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
        this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
            this.category = params['mainCategory'];
            this.subCategory = params['subCategory'];

            // validate categories in some way (either service, local method or something 
            if (!this.isCatValid(this.category) || !this.isCatValid(this.subCategory)) {
                this.router.navigate(['404']);
            }   
        }
    }

    this.isCatValid(category: string): boolean {
        // validate category
    }
}
```

Alternately if you create a categoryService that you can ensure pre-loads before any routes and has call resolves you could use add a [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) route guard to your categories routes. So your categories.routing.ts looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':mainCategory',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateCategories]
  },
  {
    path: ':mainCategory/:subCategory',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateCategories]
  }
];
```

Then you just need to write a CanActivateCategories which validates the params and either returns `true` or if not valid just another `this.router.navigate(['404']);`